# What event can I bind on an option in a select multiple?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have a multiple select list like:

```
<select name="persons" id="persons" multiple size="8">
   <option id="captureMe">Test option</option>
   <option value="" disabled="disabled">─────────</option>
   <option value="FR">Franck</option>
   <option value="GE">Georges</option>
   <option value="DA">David</option>
   <option value="LU">Luc</option>
   <option value="DO">Donald</option>
   <option value="FR">FRANCOIS</option>
</select>
```

What event can I bind on `$("#captureMe")` ?

I tried some scripts like

```
$("#captureMe").change(function() {alert("got it!");});
$("#captureMe").on("change", function() {alert("got it!");});
$("#persons").on("change", "#captureMe", function() {alert("got it!");});
```

But none of these works nor with the click event.

So my question is, what event can I bind to an option in a select multiple ?

**I don't wont the event being fired from the select but from the option by itself**

*(The goal could be firing an ajax call when a specific option is changed)*

Comment: you have to call the change functio with select box id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `click` event instead of `change`:

```js
$("#captureMe").on('click', function(){
    console.log("got it!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="persons" id="persons" multiple size="8">
   <option id="captureMe">Test option</option>
   <option value="" disabled="disabled">─────────</option>
   <option value="FR">Franck</option>
   <option value="GE">Georges</option>
   <option value="DA">David</option>
   <option value="LU">Luc</option>
   <option value="DO">Donald</option>
   <option value="FR">FRANCOIS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't achieve this by myself, but your solution works.. Thanks. Do you know if there are some other event that can be binded to an option in a multiple select ?

Comment: @GilleQ., I think you can trigger something if the selected option contains certain value on change of the whole select, but I'm not aware of another event for the `option` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look to the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="persons" id="persons" multiple size="8">
   <option id="captureMe">Test option</option>
   <option value="" disabled="disabled">─────────</option>
   <option value="FR">Franck</option>
   <option value="GE">Georges</option>
   <option value="DA">David</option>
   <option value="LU">Luc</option>
   <option value="DO">Donald</option>
   <option value="FR">FRANCOIS</option>
</select>
</body>
  <script>
     $("#persons").change(function() {
       var values = $("#persons").val();
       if($.inArray($("#captureMe").val(), values) > -1){
         if(!$("#captureMe").prop("isSelected")){
           $("#captureMe").prop("isSelected", true);
           console.log("'caputreMe' is selected");
         }
       }else{
         if($("#captureMe").prop("isSelected")){
           $("#captureMe").prop("isSelected", false);
           console.log("'caputreMe' is unselected");
         }
       }
     });
  </script>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change", "#persons", function() {alert("got it!");});
```

Comment: This way if I change another option than `#captureMe´ the event will be fired anyway, and that is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use the :selected selector, see https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $("#captured-by-id:selected").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/0mtney8j/).

Answer (score 0):

isn't it possible to make it work in following way?

```
var selectedValue = "";

$("#persons").change(function() {

var values = $(this).val();
if()// condition to check if #captureme option is present in "selectedValue" variable
{
// logic
}
else if() // condition to check if #captureme was not present in "selectedValue" before and is selected now
{
 // logic
}

selectedValue = value;
});
```